# Django - DRF - particular prefetch query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I need your help for a particular query
I have a list of missions, a mission is a package of one or more service offers and a service offer is a service with customer specific parameters (price, duration, ...) and I want to filter missions on a service.

Example:

Missions :

```
[
name : 010101
Service offers labels : facelift, painting
date : 08/22/2015 2:00pm
]
[...]
```

If I search all missions with "facelift" service like this :

```
    Mission.objects.select_related('costumer')
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
           'service_offers',
           queryset = ServiceOffer.objects.select_related('service')
                                  .filter(service__name__exact = "facelift")
        )
    )
```

The result will be

```
name : Mission 1
Service offers labels : facelift
date : 08/22/2015 2:00pm
```

but I want

```
name : Mission 1
Service offers labels : facelift, painting
date : 08/22/2015 2:00pm
```

Comment: So you don't want to filter down the `service_offers` to just the `facelift` ones? Remove the custom queryset for the `Prefetch`. Otherwise it's difficult to tell what you are looking for here.

Comment: It's okay :) If the filter is on the main queryset, it works